# SQL Server / OPENJSON / COGNITIVE SERVICE / LUIS

Tags: json, sql-server

I have this JSON:

```
{
    "query": "meu problema não foi resolvido",
    "prediction": {
        "topIntent": "Problem_not_resolved",
        "intents": {
            "Problem_not_resolved": {
                "score": 0.89767915
            },
            "Product_Quality": {
                "score": 0.09048716
            },
            "None": {
                "score": 0.00640945463
            }
        },
        "entities": {}
    }
}
```

(Items `'Problem_not_resolved'`, `'Product_Quality'` and `'None'` are unknown and on each call new labels can be listed here).

In SQL Server, I run this command:

```
SELECT *
FROM OPENJSON (@V_JSON, '$.prediction.intents')
```

SELECT result:

[image]

How do I create a select command to capture the value of the "score" field for each of the items?

Comment: This is mainly an SQL problem, so you should change your tags. In addition, SQL only takes the value in the field, so you would have to do more processing yourself (of my knowledge, please correct me if I'm wrong.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you need an additional `OPENJSON()` call with explicit schema (the `WITH` clause) to parse the nested JSON:

JSON:

```
DECLARE @json nvarchar(max) = N'{
    "query": "meu problema não foi resolvido",
    "prediction": {
        "topIntent": "Problem_not_resolved",
        "intents": {
            "Problem_not_resolved": {
                "score": 0.89767915
            },
            "Product_Quality": {
                "score": 0.09048716
            },
            "None": {
                "score": 0.00640945463
            }
        },
        "entities": {}
    }
}'
```

Statement:

```
SELECT j1.[key], j2.score
FROM OPENJSON(@json, '$.prediction.intents') j1
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(j1.[value]) WITH (score float '$.score') j2
```

Result:

```
----------------------------------
key                     score
----------------------------------
Problem_not_resolved    0.89767915
Product_Quality         0.09048716
None                    0.00640945463
```

Comment: Done!! Muito obrigado!! (thank you very much in portuguese)